# AWS: How do I support more than 2 policies in IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my project, I'm using EC2, SQS, EC3. But in IAM, I see that it can only support up to 2 policies. How do I use all three services with the same IAM key and secret?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one kind of policy in AWS.  The *managed* policies are a layer added on top of the existing *inline* policies which can be attached to a user or group.

The existing IAM policy documentation is here:

- *[Permissions and Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies.html)*
- *[Managed Policies and Inline Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies_managed-vs-inline.html)*

To read more about managed policies, read the introduction here:

- *[New – Managed Policies for AWS Identity & Access Management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-policies-for-aws-identity-access-management/)* (February 2015).
- *[An Easier Way to Manage Your Policies](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxWY3VQC1NG45/An-Easier-Way-to-Manage-Your-Policies)*